# Trainable queries for MultiHeadAttention layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I am currently building a model with a multi head attention layer, for which I would like to use the tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention layer that is already available.

My problem is that the queries need to be given as input to the layer, but I would like to train them, so I basically need a trainable constant as input to the layer. I was able to get this constant by implementing a custom layer that just returns the matrix of weights, but then the tensor does not have the dimension of the batch, such that there is a mismatch if I give it as input to the multi head attention.

How can I create such a variable to train the queries for the multi head attention?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can't you just provide a vector and let it broadcast?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was not aware of the broadcast_to function, and other tries with different functions failed previously.

Comment: Me neither, I'm a PyTorch guy ;-)

Comment: @MarcFelix Welcome to SO! it seems you have found the answer to your own question. Feel free to write and add your answer, it might help others with similar query.